# Calculation the numbers which more than 15 digits through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format

as far as I concern, it is permissible in VBA to do the calculation larger than 15 digits which giving you no zeroes automatically after the fifteenth digit -> more accuracy.

The idea is, the calculation could be done in VBA. The wished result(1,0700700070000700000**7654321**) can be presented in excel as a string data type through format conversion(it is just to show in Excel sheet not to be calculated)

Question:

1 + 0.07007000700007000007654321

-> Excel gives 1.07007000700007000008

Expectation: 1.07007000700007000007654321

Here are my codes:

```
    Sub test()
    Dim y As Double
    Dim m As String

    'cell(1,1) is where 0.07007000700007000007654321
    y = 1 + Cells(1, 1)

    m = CStr(y)

    Cells(2, 1).Value = m

    End Sub
```

Thanks for the time and knowledge, guys!

Comment: Will need to store it as a string.  Then parse the string to add the value to the part you care about, then concatenate them back together.  VBA will only store 15 sig digits and as soon as you add 1 to the number the double will round it to 15 sig dig.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46719869/storing-and-performing-calculations-on-long-decimals-in-excel-without-being-roun

Comment: There's also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32943905/multiply-two-100-digit-numbers-inside-excel-using-matrix/33016197#33016197 which is an example of long multiplication. It could easily be adapted for addition, but as has been pointed out that still leaves all the functions to be implemented not to mention subtraction and division. If your question is about addition specifically I'd be happy to try and post an answer on the same lines.

Answer (score 0):

Use *Decimal* - which needs a variable declared as *Variant*:

```vb
    Dim y As Variant
    Dim m As String

    'cell(1,1) is where 0.07007000700007000007654321
    y = 1 + CDec(Cells(1, 1))

    m = CStr(y)

    ' m -> "1.07007000700007000007654321"
```